# Client Side Filtering with combineLatest operator in RxJS not working, is there something wrong with the assignment?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am implementing Client Side Filtering in my Angular Application using RxJS streams. I have converted all my filters and data into observables and implemented the imperative logic for filtering too.

For reference, the original data-stream is called displayGroupList$ and the filtered data-stream is called filteredList$. My question is even though I am not assigning or pushing any new value to displayGroupList$, why is the data getting changed in the stream?

To explain in detail, the value changes only after there is any filter operation. Suppose the UI changed the datefilter, the first iteration gives correct filteredList but if the datefilter is changed again, the whole function fails because the `displayGroupList` is changed now which is suppose to remain constant

```js
//ngOnInit Hook

ngOnInit() {
  this.displayGroupList$ = of(this.task$.getTasks());
  if(!this.displayGroupList$) {
    this.task$.setTaskCount(0)
  } 

  this.groupFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  this.dateFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject("");
  this.titleFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject ("");

  //Create filteredList observable to subscribe in html.
  this.filteredList$ = this.createFilteredList(this.displayGroupList$, this.groupFilter$, this.dateFilter$, this.titleFilter$);
}     

// Create Filtered List
public createFilteredList(
  displayGroupList$ : Observable <Group[]>,
  groupFilter$: Observable <number>,
  dateFilter$: Observable <string>,
  titleFilter$: Observable <string>){

    return combineLatest(
      displayGroupList$,
      groupFilter$,
      dateFilter$,
      titleFilter$, (displayGroupList:Group[], groupFilter:number, dateFilter:string, titleFilter:string) => {

       //When I console.log here,
      //for no reason at all the displayGroupList is changed,
     //don't understand why. 
        console.log(displayGroupList);

        if (groupFilter === 0 && dateFilter === "" && titleFilter === "") return displayGroupList;

        let tempGroupList = displayGroupList;

        if(groupFilter){
          tempGroupList =  tempGroupList.filter((group)=> {
            return group.id === groupFilter
          })
        }

        if(dateFilter){
            for(let group of tempGroupList){
              group.tasks = group.tasks.filter((task)=> {
                return task.date === dateFilter
              })
            }
        }

        if(titleFilter){
            for(let group of tempGroupList){
              group.tasks = group.tasks.filter((task)=> {
                return task.title === titleFilter
              })
            }
        }

        return tempGroupList
      });
}
```

If the displayGroupList remains unchanged, I am assuming the filter would work perfectly

Comment: So your issue is that `displayGroupList$` stream has its value changed when you set `filteredList$` ? I don't quite get your issue there. Could you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: Exactly, displayGroupList$ needs to remain constant because it is not touched in the whole code, but it keeps changing to the filteredList$ value everytime combineLatest runs.

Comment: I think the problem is that your referencing the original list in this line `let tempGroupList = displayGroupList;` and by changing the reference your changing the original list. A quick fix would be to create a copy of your original list instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/9423231 or try `let tempGroupList = displayGroupList.slice()`

Answer (score 0):

```
return combineLatest(
  displayGroupList$,
  groupFilter$,
  dateFilter$,
  titleFilter$, (
    displayGroupList:Group[], 
    groupFilter:number, 
    dateFilter:string, 
    titleFilter:string
  ) => { ... });
```

I don't know where this syntax comes from, but here you're giving your `combineLatest` the result of an anonymous function (i.e. a function you did not call). Of course the parameters are empty !

If you wish to do that, the syntax is

```
return combineLatest(
  displayGroupList$,
  groupFilter$,
  dateFilter$,
  titleFilter$
).pipe(
  map(([displayGroupList, groupFilter, dateFilter, titleFilter]) => { ... })
);
```

Comment: Did follow the above code, but the changing problem of `displayGroupList` with `filteredList` still persists. 

If this is not the right way to do client side filtering which has multiple input sources, please suggest a more robust way.

Comment: @NishanthSubramanya please provide a [mcve]. You're only providing the code you think is relevant, but for all I know you might do `display = filter` somewhere ... https://stackblitz.com can help you make it !